# cabeçalhos Tamanho do bloco

Tags: css, css3

Então pessoal, gostaria de ajuda aqui com css.

Por exemplo:

Tenho um h3

```
<h3> Bem Vindo ao Portal do Cliente </h3>
```

Quando vou ver no navegador, tenho o texto e a caixa do h3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu queria é fazer com que a caixa do h3 ficasse do tamanho do texto. Isto é, que o width se limitasse ao final do texto automaticamente sem ter que informar um tamanho em pixels.

Retirar aquela espaço em branco após o texto.

Tem como fazer isso?

Pode notar que coloquei width com tamanho pequeno mas a caixa do h3 continua grande embora o texto tenho encolhido. Note que após o texto existe uma parte colorida até o fim da linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente colocar no h3 um display: inline;

Comment: Como esta fazendo no momento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```css
header{
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   float: left;
}
h3{
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h3>Bem Vindo ao Portal do Cliente</h3>
  </header>
```

Ou assim:

```css
header{
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h3>Bem Vindo ao Portal do Cliente</h3>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h3 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h3> Bem Vindo ao Portal do Cliente </h3>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Vi que já deram a resposta correta. Mas faltou uma explicação para o ocorrido.

O h3 tem por padrão um `display: block;` para que ele sirva de cabeçalho ocupando todo o espaço do linha para que o seu texto comece embaixo dele. Então mesmo que você diminua a sua largura, ele ainda vai ocupar todo o espaço com margem (laranja).

Então duas duas opções, se fizer questão que seja um `h3`, embora eu não veja porque seria necessário, seria ou fazer como te indicaram com um `float: left;`, porque dessa forma você faria ela flutuar à esquerda e liberaria a sua margem, ou mudar o display para `inline`, pois assim ele seria tratado como um texto qualquer e não tomaria todo o espaço.